# List any type sort

Tags: scala

I've got a list. but the type is any.

```
// list: List[List[Any]] = List(List(b, 50), List(a, 25), List(i, 60))
val list = List( List("b", 50), List("a", 25), List("i", 60))


// sort should be list(0)(0) "String" sort
("a", 25), ("b", 50), ("i", 60)

// or  list(0)(1) "Integer" sort
("a", 25), ("b", 50), ("i", 60)
```

I want to sort. How can I do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the inner lists always pairs of a string and an int? Then you should use a list of tuples instead of a list of lists to make it type safe: `val list = List(("b", 50), ("a", 25), ("i", 60))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to sort a list like this is inherently unsafe since the compiler cannot guarantee that the elements of the inner lists have the correct types.  Perhaps the safest way to accomplish this would be do use a `match` to convert the particular element, and to raise an exception is the data is not what is should be.

```
list.sortBy(x =>
  x(0) match {
    case s: String => s
    case _ => sys.error("not a string")
  })                                            
//> res0: List[List[Any]] = List(List(a, 25), List(b, 50), List(i, 60))

list.sortBy(x =>
  x(1) match {
    case i: Int => i
    case _ => sys.error("not an integer")
  })                                            
//> res1: List[List[Any]] = List(List(a, 25), List(b, 50), List(i, 60))
```

That said, it sounds like what you *really* need is a list of `(String, Int)` tuples.  That way the compiler can guarantee safety:

```
val list2 = List(("b", 50), ("a", 25), ("i", 60))                                                  
//> list2  : List[(java.lang.String, Int)] = List((b,50), (a,25), (i,60))
```

Notice that the compiler knows the types of the inner elements.  So sorting is much easier, *and safer*:

```
list2.sortBy(_._1)                              
//> res2: List[(java.lang.String, Int)] = List((a,25), (b,50), (i,60))
list2.sortBy(_._2)                              
//> res3: List[(java.lang.String, Int)] = List((a,25), (b,50), (i,60))
```

Answer (score 2):

To sort by first and second elements use this:

```
scala> list.sortBy{
     |   case (s: String) :: (i: Int) :: Nil => s -> i
     |   case _ => sys.error("error")
     | }
res0: List[List[Any]] = List(List(a, 25), List(b, 50), List(i, 60))
```

You can use `case (s: String) :: _ => s` to sort by first element or `case _ :: (i: Int) :: _ => i` to sort by second element.